# How reload configuration file on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, log4net, windows-server-2008-r2

My application uses:

- .NET 4
- MVC 3
- Windows Server 2008 R2

I use `log4net` to write to a log file. My configuration file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Temp\log.txt">
      <some settings for log4net...>
    </appender>
  <log4net>
</configuration>
```

I want to change the file value while the application is running, from

`<file value="C:\Temp\log.txt">`

to

`<file value="C:\Logs\MyAppLog.txt">`

It worked great when I ran the app on my computer (localhost), but a problem occurs when I run the app on a server. I change the configurations, but the server remembers the old configurations. Why doesn't the server load the file every single time?

Comment: Is the c:\Logs folder already created on the server?

Comment: yes, created on server.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

Watch means that log4net will pick up changes in the config file. You can also configure this in your application configuration.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
  <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
</appSettings>
```

If it stop logging the temp dir, and does not start in de logs dir, you probably have a permissions problem. Give your apppool user access to the logs directory.

If that is not working, you can enable log4net internal debuging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

or:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Server has permissions to write. I think so because I see that he is writing to a file, the problem is that the server does not read or load the configuration at any given moment.